# MySQL выборка в 1 запрос

Tags: mysql

Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE  `dump` (
  `wid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mtime` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Задача выбрать последнюю запись для каждого wid.
(групировка по wid но при таком подходе выбирает случайную запись, а нужно запись с максимальным mtime).
Таблица - история изменения записей, из нее требуется получить текущий вариант таблици.(пишутся не сами изменения а текущий вариант изменившихся данных, неизмененные записи не добавляются).

```
Вопросы:
1) Как максимально быстро сделать требуемую выборку? желательно 1 запрос.
2) Нужны ли индексы для данной таблици?(если да то доп поле или на какие либо из текущих?)
3) Как лучше реализовать добавление записей(как они должны добавлятся выше)?(имеется ввиду на самом MySQL смотреть менялась ли запись или нет или на php).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как ответить на ваши вопросы. Сами как думаете?

ЗЫ:

```
select d.wid, d.data1, d.data2, d.data3, d.mtime
from dump d
  join (select wid, max(mtime) mtime
    from dump
    group by wid) md 
  on d.wid = md.wid and d.mtime=md.mtime;
```

Comment: сам думаю так:
1) 2 запроса, временная таблица(выборка уникальных wid и максимального времени, выборка данных к ним).
2)Индексы на wid и time(можно даже 2 ключа).
3)php

Но это мои мысли))

Comment: 1. достаточно одного запроса (см. запрос в ответе), впрочем можно и временной таблицей. считайте, что временная таблица создается и так - как вложенный запрос. и на самом деле так и происходит.  
2. ну, смотрите. у вас уникальным является пара wid, mtime. соответственно выборка конкретной записи у вас будет идти по этой паре, т.е получили для каждого wid свой mtime (та самая временная таблица). Значит по этой паре нужен ключ.
3. не совсем понятно что значит как вставлять записи. записи вставляются для любой таблицы одинаково. php значит php.

мысли у вас верные, не бойтесь пробовать.

Comment: Пробовать небоюсь, но данные мысли после пары "ожогов" пришли, вот и решил "проконсультироватся", имеется ввиду на чем искать изменения? на пхп? или писать функцию на MySQL, если на пхп то все понятно делаем выборку(о которой речь выше) и сравниваем.. если MySQL- то для меня это темный лес.

Comment: Все очень просто. Если у вас бизнес-логика находится в php, то и сравнение лучше делать там. Да, можно в mysql триггер на update и insert сделать, будет то же самое, только часть бизнес-логики будет в базе. И то и то имеет право на жизнь, и пока **вы** не решили как правильнее, делайте как удобнее именно вам. Производительность сильно не пострадает, в любом случае.

Comment: Спасиб, вроде все вопросы разжевали.. плюсик в карму от меня) и попутный вопрос, что лучше(или это одно и тоже?)

    select d1.id,d1.data,d2.data from table1 d1,table2 d2, where d1.id=d2.id;
или тожесамое джоином?

Comment: с точки зрения mysql план запроса будет одинаков (будет приведение к join'у). но лучше использовать join'ы, т.к. во-первых понятнее синтаксис (когда будет 10 таблиц в запросе, оцените). во-вторых, ANSI стандарт. в третьих, в варианте с where есть возможность нарваться на декартово произведение, просто забыв указать какой-либо предикат. в четвертых (но не для этого запроса), left join написать синтаксисом с where можно, но получится более многословно - доп сравнение с null, в общем неудобно.

Comment: брр)) тут реч об обычном и инер джоинах, левый и правый в расчет не берутся. если чесно мне с ними тяжелей понять что к чему, в варианте с условием(5-6 таблиц, больше не пробовал) проще намного)

Comment: :) ну это вопрос привыкания. 
* mysql [Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
* mssql [SR0010: не используйте устаревший синтаксис при объединении таблиц или представлений](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd172122.aspx)
* oracle [...it is recommended to follow the standards whenever possible...](http://awads.net/wp/2006/03/16/back-to-basics-cross-joins/)